# How can I put a picture in a side column?

Tags: floats, formatting

I have a standard template for a diary and moved the text to the left with geometry.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

Now I want to place the pictures as floats on the right side next to the text. I thought about a two column layout, but then there will be also text in the second column. Ideal would be a solution similar to the [SIGCHI Extended Abstract Template](https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/association-for-computing-machinery-acm-sigchi-extended-abstract-template/zzzfqvkmrfzn), but my LaTeX skills are not good enough to add similar behavior to my document.

Could you tell me what packets are responsible or needed for this to work?

Comment: Probably you could use the marginfigure environment from the sidenotes package.

Comment: @leandriis yeah something like this would be great. Do you have an idea, how i could apply this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simplified MWE that can serve as a starting point is the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{This is a marginfigure with a caption}
\end{marginfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```